# PageReference.getContent cause System.VisualforceException: No Visualforce context has been established!

Tags: apex

I was using **PageReference.getContent** to grab a file from an external source but today it starts to cause error:

> System.VisualforceException: No Visualforce context has been
>   established!

It's quite strange behavior, I am not sure on what it depends because earlier it was working well and I was able to successfully run the same code on other few orgs.

**Solution** is to use another approach:

```
HttpRequest requestObj = new HttpRequest();
requestObj.setMethod('GET');
requestObj.setEndpoint('<target-url>');
Http httpObj = new Http();
HttpResponse responseObj = httpObj.send(requestObj );
Blob blobContent = responseObj.getbodyasblob();
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include your code.

Comment: is the failing org on Spring 19?

Comment: no, its Winter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by using another approach of getting content by url:

```
HttpRequest requestObj = new HttpRequest();
requestObj.setMethod('GET');
requestObj.setEndpoint('<target-url>');
Http httpObj = new Http();
HttpResponse responseObj = httpObj.send(requestObj );
Blob blobContent = responseObj.getbodyasblob();
```

To someone, it might save time.