# Enabling session setting "Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated" and My Domain breaks PageReference.getContent()

Tags: apex, session

After enabling My Domain and the "Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated", calls to PageReference.getContent() fail with a 403 refused connection error.

Is our only course of action to disable the Lock sessions feature?  Or is there a way to either reset the session ID or configure the correct domain before making the getContent call?

Comment: If the content is external to SF, try a more direct extraction approach, e.g. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246089/pagereference-getcontent-cause-system-visualforceexception-no-visualforce-conte

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  However, our call is internal.